# Add Custom PHTML Templates to Magento CMS Pages

Tags: magento

I'm just learning Magento, so, I just went through this tut on youtube about how to create a custom template. Everything went fine until I had to change the `<codePool>` to local.

With the default `<codePool>core</codePool>` I can see the new template I created(duplicated 1column.phtml and changed the name) but not my changes in it because instead of 1column is showing 3column layout. If I change `<codePool>` to local, `<codePool>local</codePool>`, I get a white page with nothing in it.

These are the steps of what I did. Can anyone help me on this? I'm using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4. Thanks.

------------- ADDING A CUSTOM TEMPLATE -------------------
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=144V9aSmhZc

1. Go to:
   app/design/frontend/default/theme-you-are-using/template/page/

   then copy one of the templates.
2. Then go to:
   app/code/local/

   and create the dir structure:
   /Mage/Page/etc/

   at the end it should look like this:
   app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/
3. Now go to:
   app/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml

   and copy it to:

   app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/
4. Open 'config.xml' and go to the `<layout>` section and add your changes,e.g.

   ```
   <reward-points module="page" translate="label">
    <label>Reward Points</label>
    <template>page/rewards.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>page_rewards</layout_handle>
   </reward-points>
   ```
5. After that, open:
   app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml

   go to  and change  to 'local', so it'll look like this:

   ```
   <codePool>local</codePool>
   ```
6. Now, go to System/Cache Management and 'Flush Magento Cache'
7. Go to CMS/Pages click any page and to the left click the Design tab. Now the 'Layout' dropdown should show the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

Copying core files in local gives you result, but doing so will not include the core methods after upgrades.So you can add custom phtml template by registering your module

> app/etc/modules

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
           <Custom_Pagelayout>
                 <codePool>local</codePool>
                 <active>true</active>
          </Custom_Pagelayout>
     </modules>
</config>
```

Now create folder structure for your module in local.

> Custom/Pagelayout/etc

add config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <global>
      <page>
           <layouts>
                <custom_phtml_file>
                     <label>Custom phtml</label>
                     <template>page/custom.phtml</template>
                </custom_phtml_file>
       </layouts>
      </page>
 </global>
</config>
```

Then add custom.phtml in your theme.